# Add New Window Attribute to CQ Page Redirects

Tags: adobe, aem

I am trying to add a *target='_blank'* option to all CQ pages that only redirect to either an outside URL or media file (i.e. PDF). I am looking in components/parsys/parsys.php which I assume would have some block of code for a server-/client-side redirect but to no avail.

I realize that if the redirect is in fact server-side then I cannot open it in a new window. But until I know either way, can someone help point out where the actual redirect script code is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the out of box redirect mechanism (where you fill out the redirect target on the Page Properties dialog), the default redirect logic can be found under:

```
 /libs/foundation/components/page/page.jsp (CQ 5.4)
```

The code is doing response.sendRedirect so you may not be able to force redirects to open in new windows from there.

Comment: Ah, so the code is server-side, so my feature is no go. At least I am certain now.